# How to create custom reports in custom menu in admin magento 2?

Tags: magento2, admin, custom-reports

Actually i want create custom report based on sales ,product and custom data from custom module in admin side with graph

Comment: why dont you check vendor\magento\module-reports\ and duplicate it?

Comment: I think it shows only grid not graphical view

Comment: you can rewrite layout to get rid of grid and use your template for diagrams or whatsoever. actually it will be much simpler without grid. anyway, default module give you idea on how to handle data you need for report

Comment: is it possible to get order report by selecting customer ??